# How to configure a mouse in linux?

Tags: mouse, settings, xbindkeys

I just freshly installed an archlinux and just received my new mouse Mx anywhere 2. As the mouse have more than two buttons and i' wondering how to configure these buttons ?

I already checked a bit on archlinux doc which say that you have to set the configuration on .xbindkeysrc but it doesn't seems to work.
Does anyone has a clue how to configure the mouse buttons easily ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a fair amount of success for Linux users in relation to Logitech mice using the HIDPoint solutions. Personally, I used this solution about 3 years ago when I was having issues with another MX-series mouse while using openSUSE.

Here is a link:
https://www.hidpoint.com/hidpoint

Good Luck!!!

Comment: it doesn't work with archlinux